# How to make nested AND's and OR's in DB queries in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I was wondering how I can get something like this:

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE id='1' AND (title='hurr' OR title='durr')
```

in Zend framework? To my knowledge there are only `where()` functions, which together make AND relationships and `orWhere()` which adds an OR rule, but if used together, a select like this:

```
$select=$this->select()->where("id='1'")->where("title='hurr'")->orWhere("title='durr'");
```

This would create a query like this

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE id='1' AND title='hurr' OR title='durr'
```

Which is something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$select = $this->select()->where('id = 1')->where("title='durr' OR title='hurr'");

$select = $this->select()->where('id = 1')->where('title IN (?)', array('durr', 'hurr'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$select=$this->select()->where("id='1'")->where("title='hurr' OR title='durr'");
```

You can check the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where)